# Question about the difference in allocating memory in the code snippets?

Tags: c, struct

Can anyone explain the difference in why allocating memory to the structures are different here?
Thanks.

```
typedef struct Node{
int data;
struct Node *next;
}Node;

Node *newNodePtr = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
```

vs

```
struct Person {
char *name;
int age;
int height; 
int weight;
};

struct Person *who = malloc(sizeof(struct Person));
```

Comment: I don’t see any difference, beside the fact that they have different size. To which difference are you referring to?

Comment: Are you asking about why one casts the return from `malloc()` and the other doesn't, or are you really wondering about the types (one using a pointer to a  `typedef` of a struct and the other just using a pointer to a struct)?  The cast is optional (and often not recommended in C)... otherwise the memory is allocated the same way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

struct Node is typedefd to Node so the sizeof(Node) is legal, because there is no typedef for Person you cold not do sizeof(Person). The cast to (Node*) on the malloc is unnecessary, C allows cast from void * to other object type pointers without a cast (and plenty of people recommend against it).

Answer (score -2):

```
sizeof(Person) == sizeof(char*) + 3*sizeof(int) == 16
sizeof(Node) == sizeof(int) + sizeof(Node*) == 8
```

In c, all pointers have the same size. Assuming 32bit system, it's 4 bytes, as a conventional int.

Comment: Did you mean `sizeof(struct Person)`? And don't forget the possibity of `struct` member padding. It is dangerous to assume any sum of the size of each member: `sizeof` is the right tool. How does this answer the question, which is not about size?

Comment: It is common for pointers in a C implementation to have the same size, but this is not required by the C standard; it is implementation-dependent. Nor is there any requirement about the relationship between the size of pointers, the size of `int`, or the purported “32-bit” nature of the system. Pointers to structures must have the same sizes as each other, pointers to unions must have the same size as each other, and pointers to compatible types must have the same size as each other, but, otherwise, pointers may have different sizes and internal representations.